# Swift 5: identify all different substrings in string

Tags: string, substring, xcode11, swift5

I have the following string:

`var strOfCharToSort = "azcdczbdxaaczdbbaazdz"`

but I'm trying to get the count of the different substrings

for example:

`let countofA = strOfCharToSort.filter { $0 == "a" }.count`

and it works but I don't know what substrings are in the string I'm loading

I can sort the string:

`strOfCharToSort = String(strOfCharToSort.sorted()) \\ result: aaaaabbbcccddddxzzzzz`

But my question to guys there is a way to split the string when if finds a different substring?

I'll really appreciate you help.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
let strOfCharToSort = "azcdczbdxaaczdbbaazdz"
let setOfChars = Set(strOfCharToSort)
let setOfCharsArray = Array(setOfChars).sorted()
let listOfSortedCharSubstrings = setOfCharsArray.map { (charachter) in
    return strOfCharToSort.filter { $0 == charachter }
}
```

This is a solution to get the sub strings of a sorted character array.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
let StringOfChar = "azcdczbdxaaczdbbaazdz"
let SetOfAllChar = Set(StringOfChar)
for char in SetOfAllChar {
    let countofChar = StringOfChar.filter { $0 == char }.count
    print("Count of \(char) : \(countofChar)")
}
```

**Output:**

```
Count of d: 4
Count of z: 5
Count of c: 3
Count of b: 3
Count of a: 5
Count of x: 1
```